# Create java session using ajax/js (jpa, jsp, sign in)

Tags: javascript, ajax, session, authentication

I need to create a session using ajax/js in my login system. I'm using jpa, jsp, js and that's how it looks like.

In my login file i have something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/knockout-3.2.0.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/UserLoginModel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var viewModel = new UserLoginModel();
  $(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  })()
</script>
<%
  if(sessions.getAttribute("loggedInUser") == null) {
%>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Podaj login" data-bin="value: login"><br />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Podaj haslo" data-bin="value: password"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Sign in">
  </form>
<% } %>
```

There is content of my UserLoginModel.js file:

```
UserLoginModel = function()
{
    var self = this;
    self.login = ko.observable();
    self.password = ko.observable();

    self.save= function()
    {
        var data = ko.toJSON(self);
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/EPC_war_exploded/resources/users/log",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                window.location="index.jsp";
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, testStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

There is my method which has "/log" path:

```
@POST
@Path("/log")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Transactional
public String signIn(UserSummaryDto user) {

    //here I will check if user exists in database
}
```

So the only problem I have it's how to create the "loggedInUser" session, to be visible by java, by the file where login form is? How to do it even without check if user exists, just to know how to make it because in pure java code I can do something like:

```
  HttpSession sessions = request.getSession(false);
  sessions.setAttribute("loggedInUser", login);
```

because either I checked like that:

```
  <%
    String login = request.getParameter("login");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "user", "password");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='" + login + "' AND password='" + password + "'");
    if(rs.next()) {
      out.println("Zalogowany prawidłowo.");
      HttpSession sessions = request.getSession(false);
      sessions.setAttribute("loggedInUser", login);
      response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    } else {
      out.println("Nazwa użytkownika, lub hasło są nieprawidłowe.");
    }
  %>
```

I know that's a lot to read but the question is simple - How to create a session using ajax/js. Thanks you for you help and your time.

Comment: No JPA involved in the posted info. You use JDBC.

Comment: I have all classes with EntityManager and all works great. I show only how I check user in database but the question is - how to create a session using ajaX/JS.